# VS2010 add-in to show target framework in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in

Is there a VS2010 add-in that shows a project's target framework version in the Solution Explorer window?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly in Solution Explorer, but with [this plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) you can see and change target frameworks of all your projects in one place.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.